# How can I appropriately model relationships that have a cyclical dependency?

Tags: design, database-design, ruby-on-rails, domain-model

Let's take two simple Rails models, Post and PostRevision.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  # Attribute: Status (ex: draft, public, private, deleted)
  # Attribute: Views

  # An owner, likely a belongs_to relation. Perhaps a has_many relation.

  has_many :post_revisions
  validates :post_revisions, :presence => true

  has_many :comments

  has_many :votes

  # Delegation to most recent active / not deleted PostRevision for title,
  # body, tags to effectively expose these attributes
end

class PostRevision < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post

  # Attribute: Title
  # Attribute: Body
  # Attribute: Status (ex: deleted / not deleted, perhaps just an int flag)
  # Attribute: Views

  # Attribute: Revision history notes / text.

  # If a Post has_many owners, an attribute for author/owner of revision

  has_many :tags
end
```

The default behavior of the "belongs to" association is to require that the associated record is present (that is, a PostRevision must have a Post - this can be disabled with an argument).

This model is conceptually true, however there's an problem that exhibits itself in test setup and controller actions - [see this Stack Overflow question on "1-to-1 or more" relationships in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5538688/572). You can't create a PostRevision until there's a Post, but you need a valid PostRevision to create a Post. I see two options - I can make the "belongs to" relation in the PostRevision optional. This will let me create a PostRevision first then a Post and associate them. Alternatively, I can remove the validation of the existence of a PostRevision on a Post. This would let me create a Post and then multiple PostRevision.

I'm leaning toward the second approach - remove the validation on Post. However, I can't actually put into words *why* this is the better option, other than it feels more right to create the Post and the things that cut across revisions and then the revision with the rest of the data.

Is there an alternative approach that I haven't considered? If not, is there some kind of rational justification to the approach that I'm leaning toward?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done Rails work.  When does the validation kick in?  If you create the first revision at the same time as the post itself and save the duo, is everything happy?  Is having the new post be the first revision conceptually what you are after?

Comment: @BerinLoritsch The validation kicks in on a save. The first save is also when an object gets its ID in the database. I'm not aware of a way to save both at the same time in Rails. Perhaps a Rails limitation? I'm preferably looking for something that is more abstract than Rails, as well. I just expressed the ideas in Rails since I happen to be working in Rails.

Comment: Is the association immutable?

Comment: @CandiedOrange What do you mean by immutable?

Comment: I mean are you hoping to not ever change the associated ID or can it be fiddled with during construction?

Comment: @CandiedOrange The PostRevision is only ever associated with one Post. It doesn't make sense to me to say that a PostRevision can suddenly belong to a different Post. As far as construction, the IDs are generated automatically when the object is saved and provide the foreign key relationship between a PostRevision and it's Post.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense for it to be associated with no post at all. But you're chicken and egg problem demands that something give. I'm submitting that you can also solve this with a known bad egg that stands in for the egg you'll associate with after it exists.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Associating a PostRevision with a dummy Post seems even more clumsy than removing the requirement that a Post has at least one PostRevision. It seems more OK to have a Post exist for a short period of time without a PostRevision during initial creation, especially if the action to create a new Post creates a Post and it's first PostRevision. I would just need additional rules around deleting all PostRevisions leaving a Post with none. But "it works and it feels right" doesn't seem like a good way to make a design decision, and this type of relationship isn't uncommon.

Comment: @ThomasOwens ya asked for an alternative approach. Keeping the cyclic validation requirement creates a need for a transaction. What you haven't explained is why creation might be interrupted. If nothing else knows either of these exists yet they can't be caught with their pants down halfway through creation. If that's the case then removing the validation and leaving it blank is fine. You can trust enforcing their relationship to some methods post condition. If you want more assurance you'll want to do validation sometime after both have been saved. Are other threads roaming around?

Comment: Why in the world must a post be revised?  Your model doesn't seem to represent reality to me.

Comment: @LorenPechtel good point, I was wondering why the first post revision fields can't just be post fields. I generally try to avoid cyclic dependencies regardless of what reality thinks.

Comment: @ThomasOwens The first option seems more logical to me. Make the "belongs to" optional on the Revision entity. And, create a "Head" property in Post that always points to a single Revision. The contents always stay in the Revision entity.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not Rails specific, but a characteristics of any system which uses relational databases or the relational model as a foundation. "one-or-more" relationships and the enforcement of such a constraint are not well supported in such systems. See also [this older SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538688/database-how-to-distinguish-one-or-more-and-zero-or-more-relationship).

Comment: I have another question. Why do you need a bidirectional mapping in the code? Usually in this kind of relationship, one of the mappings is stronger or more sensible to the business logic than the other. For example, the business leans to operate and query `Posts` and its properties rather than operate and query `PostReviews`. If the consuming of PostReviews is marginal (compared with Post) I would map PostReview without the relationship. Automatically or not, at the end, I would have to hit the database in order to get further details. So, as CandiedOrange would say: "procrastination"

Comment: I've been thinking on this a while and what I can't stop disliking is that either method ends with a "single source of truth" violation. I'm only thinking about this structurally rather them semantically (since I don't really understand the context) but if you're really stuck with this I recommend considering a 3rd class: `PostHistory` that requires one `Post`, one `PostRevision`, and as many optional additional `PostRevisions` as you like. On the DB this should act like a special case of a many-to-many join table so it should be enforceable.

Comment: @LorenPechtel A Post holds things that don't change across revisions - the number of times it was viewed, if you support voting then the number of votes, comments. Comments, for example, don't go away if you edit a Post. A PostRevision holds the things that can be changed - the title can be changed, the body edited, a summary modified, etc. Post would likely delegate some methods to the most recent non-deleted non-draft PostRevision, but would have a history of all edits the many PostRevisions that it has (with each PostRevision being an edit). It seems like this models reality.

Comment: @Laiv The best example of needing both is search. Let's say I remember that, at one point in time, I was writing about X. But it may have been in an old revision of one of my posts, not my latest. So as a user, I search for PostRevisions that belong to me that contain X. I can then either view the Post that the PostRevision belongs to, either a "live, current view" or a "history view" that shows the matching PostRevision in the context of other PostRevisions. Going from a Post to all of its PostRevisions or from a PostRevision to its Post is important in at least a couple of cases.

Comment: @DocBrown That post is a really good description of the problem I'm running into. But it doesn't really say how to approach solutions in applications, especially frameworks like Rails, ASP.NET MVC, Django, or something else. I've edited that into my post so it has some more visibility to describe the technical issue that I need to design around.

Comment: Sorry in advance for the vague comment (I'm struggling my head to find the right words).  I cannot but think in either proxying the relationship (for latter/lazy initializations) and eventual consistency.

Comment: @Laiv By "eventual consistency", do you mean removing either the validation on the existence of a PostRevision or allowing a PostRevision to not need a Post at creation time and letting the system reach a state that the rules are true on its own - the two options I presented in the question? It seems like having a proxy would be even more confusing to the model - these proxies don't exist in any other model of the domain.

Comment: @ThomasOwens `removing the validation on the existence of a PostRevision` seems more natural to me (from my very little understanding and knowledge of the domain).

Comment: I think is a framework issue. If some hypothetical framework would support "one-or-more" relationsships, there would be no problem, right?  I guess the reason for so many frameworks not supporting these kind of relationships is probably, they are not well supported by relational databases, and the cyclic nature of this model causes often further problems.

Comment: ... and since you asked for an alternative approach: a `Post` could also hold the attributes of its first revision, and the `PostRevision` class/table might be used for any revision except the first one (so you will need only a "0 or more" relationship). That is surely an ugly solution, since it breaks normalization rules, but technically, it should work.

Comment: I don't think it's an ugly solution. 1-to-1 relationships often mean that both elements are in essence the same thing. Happens that for some reason we store part of it in other tables. We do this also extending legacy code when it's easier to add new tables 1-to-1 than modifying the current tables.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: can you give an example for some possible attributes of those two classes?

Comment: @DocBrown Sorry for the delay - I wanted to do this at lunch at work, but I've now updated the post with what I'm thinking the other relations and attributes on these two models would likely be.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are trying to solve is a nested form. Rails handles this with the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` class method. Basically, when you go to create a `Post`, you would also pass the nested attributes for the first `PostRevision`. Rails then creates all of the records together in a single transaction, allowing the `PostRevision` to be created before the validation on the `Post` executes.

Given a `Post` model with an `author` attribute, and a `PostRevision` model with `post_id`, `title`, and `body` attributes, here's what the code would look like:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_revisions

  validates :post_revisions, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_revisions
end

class PostRevision < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :post
end
```

Here's the command to create the `Post` and the first `PostRevision` together:

```
Post.create(
  author: 'Langston Hughes', 
  post_revisions_attributes: [
    {
      title: 'Dust and Rainbows',
      body: <<~POEM 
        Oh, God of Dust and Rainbows, 
        Help us to see
        That without the dust the rainbow 
        Would not be.
      POEM
    }
  ]
)
```